# XMLHttpRequest Replace Element Won't Work With LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, replace, xmlhttprequest

I tried to implement cookie logging with localStorage into the javascript code for replacing a specific element. It uses the XMLHttprequest method and, I got no idea why it won't work with localStorage. Please enlighten me.

```
localStorage.setItem("replace1", this.JSON.parse(responseText));

function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("replace1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("replace1"); 
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "yoinkexecutor2.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: repsonseText is an object I believe therefore use ```JSON.parse(responseText);``` and then retrieve the property from that object

Comment: it still outputs "undefined" for some reason

Comment: at which line of code do you get undefined?

Comment: I updated the post with changed code, and the element just outputs "undefined" and not showing the element at all. https://i.imgur.com/Wn4JNCI.png On the site https://natevanghacks.com/scriptexecutors2.php

Comment: I think that the problem is that you should put the ```document.getElementById("replace1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("replace1");```after  ```localStorage.setItem("replace1", this.JSON.parse(responseText));  ```because of the async behaviour, you are trying to display something before the data comes from the XHR request

Comment: Updated the post. And that did work but localStorage isn't working for the element. I really want the webserver to remember the change and not return to its default state again. It does replace the element with the url one, but the webserver returns it back after refreshing. Need it to keep the change client sided.

Comment: You can only store string in local storage, you would need to do . 
```localStorage.setItem("replace1", JSON.stringify(responseText));``` and then when retrieving it  ```JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("replace1"));```

Answer (score 0):

You can only display data when the async operation (GET) request terminates.

Otherwise you'll get undefined since nothing exits in the localStorage under that key

Also, you can only store strings in local storage, meaning you need to parse that object string once you want to retrieve the data using getItem

```
 function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      localStorage.setItem("replace1", JSON.stringify(this.responseText))
      document.getElementById("replace1").innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("replace1"))
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "yoinkexecutor2.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: But then JSON.stringify also doesn't appear to work as it outputs an error for it in console. Uncaught ReferenceError: responseText is not defined at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange. https://i.imgur.com/rEafTqI.png

Comment: check it again, it should have been ```this.responseText```

Comment: thats all great, hah. But for some reason when, I refresh the page, the element returns back to its default state. It's only when, I click on it the element changes to the url one. odd

Comment: @NateVang that's strange localStorage should persist the state.

Comment: yeah it's odd i mean you nailed everything. here you can see https://natevanghacks.com/scriptexecutors2.php when you click on Yoink Executor element, it changes to the url one but then you refresh the page it's back to it's default state. hah man code can be headache sometimes.

Comment: are you sure about that, cause when i Refresh the replace1 key value remains.. Yea it is still there, check the console.log using inspect element and type localStorage, you will see the key

Comment: yea, because when it replaces the element with the url one, it places the url's element inside the element you clicked on to be replaced. So the urls element gets put inside the <div id="replace1"> element. <div id="replace1"><div id="replace2"></div></div>.

Comment: the key is created for the element but the replaced element returns to it's default state after refreshing, makes no sense lo. @Eugene Sulic